# Linq sum anonymous collections to find total in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

i am trying to sum collections result in linq,

**Update:**

**Expected output in view :**

```
Name  TotalPoints  

Raja      411
```

I have got the output, i Used Viewbag to pass the Totalpoints and Name in View. Thanks to all.

**i get this error:**

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

**Linq Query thus far:**

```
  public ActionResult UserTotalProfile()
        {

List<TotalPointsUser> onetotal = (from T1 in dbpoints.LoayaltyPointsTable

join T2 in dbpoints.LoyaltyDetailsTable on 
T1.LoyaltyPointsId equals T2.LoyaltyPointsId
join T3 in dbpoints.CustomerTable on 
T2.CustomerId equals T3.CustomerId

select new { T3.Name, T3.CustomerId, T1.Points,T1.LoyaltyPointsId } into x
   where x.CustomerId == 1
   group x by new { x.CustomerId, x.Name ,x.Points,x.LoyaltyPointsId} into g
   select new TotalPointsUser
   {
   CustomerId = g.Key.CustomerId,
   Name = g.Key.Name,
   Points = g.Key.LoyaltyPointsId == 4 ?
 ((from RedeemPointsTable in dbpoints.RedeemPointsTable
         where
          RedeemPointsTable.CustomerId == 1
         select new
         {
             RedeemPointsTable.Amount
         }).Sum(p => p.Amount) * g.Key.Points) : g.Sum(p => p.Points)

         }).ToList();


     var list = onetotal.ToList();

     var allpoint1 = list.Sum(a => a.Points);

     var allpoint2 = onetotal.AsEnumerable().Sum(a => a.Points); // here is the error



            return View(allpoint2);


        }
```

**my anonymous collections :**

[image]

**this is calculated total**

[image]

**this my View to show total:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcPoints.Models.TotalPointsUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserTotalProfile";
}

   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {

     <div >
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
     </div>
     <div >
     Total Points <br /> <span >@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Points)</span> 
     </div>

     }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please format your code. It is currently very difficult to read.

Comment: @Yuval ltzchakov, thank you, i have formatted now, are the images readable ?

Answer (score 4):

The `Sum` method returns an integer. So on this line, the `allpoint2` variable is of type integer:

```
var allpoint2 = onetotal.AsEnumerable().Sum(a => a.Points);
```

which is what you are passing to the view:

```
return View(allpoint2);
```

But your view declaration is `IEnumerable<TotalPointsUser>`

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcPoints.Models.TotalPointsUser>
```

Thus the error you are getting.

You may consider using a complex view model which will contain the list of users and the sum:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int TotalSum {get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TotalPointsUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Now you could pass this view model to the view and update it's `@model` definition.

Comment: currently this is my model class : '  public class TotalPointsUser
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }
    }
'

Comment: Alright, in this case you should be consistent with your view `@model` declaration and what you are passing to the `return View()` method.

Comment: i have changed the whole code, [here](http://pastebin.com/16tfUeNJ) it is, but still the error persist, may i know what wrong i am doing

Comment: Can you post your edited code instead of an external pastebin? will be easier for users who reading your question without seeing this comment.